# Calculating Expected value and Variance in Octave

Tags: octave, variance

I have a set of data `(x_data,y_data)`. I want to calculate the Expected value and Variance of the data.
But before that I want to normalize it like this

[image]

Then **Expected Value**

[image]

And **Variance**

[image]

How can I do this normalization and Expected value & Variance calculation in Octave?

I tried this
**Expected value:**

```
 Exp_pre = (x_data.*y_data); 
 Expected_value = trapz(Exp_pre);
```

**Varince:**

```
 Variance = var(y_data);
```

Comment: Your data is discrete (a finite set of value `(x,y)`). Why do you want to use the continuous form of EV and Var? I think the discrete form (summation) is more appropriate.

Comment: I read a paper where they calculated EV and Variance of Experimental data and Model data. Then compared them to show how close the model is to the experimental data. I am simply trying to reproduce them. However I did curve fitting to get a y=f(x).

Comment: What is “f” in your equations? How is it related to your `(x_data,y_data) ` values? Please clarify!

Comment: f(x) is the probability density function (pdf) calculated from (x_data, y_data), as far as I understand.